# Name of view or activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, design-patterns, view

What is the name of view or activity which looks like horizontal listview of columns, cards or something else? Battery calibration app contains it, for example.

[image: example printscreen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) with a horizontal LinearLayoutManager.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Also check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)